# Nginx allow user agent specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I migrate apache to nginx.
In apache I put .htaccess inside folder, but nginx hasn't this.

I have folder /admin and it can only by accessed by User Agent: Administrator
I do:

```
location ~ /admin {
if ($http_user_agent !~* "Administrator") {
    return 404;
}
try_files $uri =404;
```

}

And it works, but .php files isn't interpreted.

How can I do this?

Edit:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  myserver.com;

root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
}

location ~ /admin {
    if ($http_user_agent !~* "Administrator") {
        return 404;
    }
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the specification about agent callback instead of `"Administrator"` it should be `(Administrator)` rest of the code seems to be ok. If you have added `try_files $uri =404;` additionally then remove it as it don't required. return 404 already defined.

Try this one

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  myserver.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }
}
location ~ /admin {
if ($http_user_agent !~* "Administrator") {
    return 404;
   }
  try_files $uri =404;
 }
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
}
```

restart nginx service before test!

Comment: The problem is when I access a .php file inside /admin, in my browser display php code.
I guess it is because .php config is on another location

Comment: will you be able to post full code, as would like to see pre-defined location methods if any

Comment: `server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  myserver.com;

 root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

 location / {
 }

 location ~ /admin {
  if ($http_user_agent !~* "Administrator") {
   return 404;
  }
  try_files $uri =404;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
 }

 include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
}`

Comment: It works but if you access /admin/login.php doesn't check user-agent :(

Comment: Have you even tried (Administrator) instead of "Administrator"

Comment: Yes.. I think NGINX just parse one location